# VSCode project wide search default entries for folders to search in

Tags: visual-studio-code

In documentation provided [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics), there is detail provided only about files/folders to exclude searching from. Essentially, this is inherited from `"files.exclude":` in `settings.json`

However, I would like to restrict my searches only to specific folders. That is, I would like to specify which folders to include in the search. My project structure is thus:

```
myproject
    ----src
       file1.cpp, ..., file10.cpp
    ----include
       incl1.h, ..., incl10.h
    ----data
       data1.txt, ..., data10.txt
```

Suppose I want to search for occurrence of word `hello` only in `./src/` and `./include/` and exclude any search returns from `./data/` folder. As of now, I can manually do the following:

[image]

Hit `<Ctrl-Shift>f`, navigate to "files to include" box and enter `src, include`. This latter step can also be accomplished by `<Ctrl-Shift>j`.

Is there a setting that can be provided in, say, the workspace setting that automatically populates the "files to include" box with `src, include` without having the user type it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any setting to populate the "files to include" input.  However, you can set up a keybinding (in `keybindings.json`) to do this pretty easily.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+f",                // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
  "args": {

    "query": "",            // some bug requires this, see below

    // "isRegex": true,
    // "replace": "$1",
    // "triggerSearch": true,

    "filesToInclude": "src, include",
    "filesToExclude": "data"

    // "preserveCase": true,
    // "useExcludeSettingsAndIgnoreFiles": false,
    // "isCaseSensitive": true,
    // "matchWholeWord": true,

  }
}
```

I included all the other available `args` to the command.  That will open the Search view with `src, include` in the "files to include" input field and `data` in the "files to exclude" input field.

In my testing, for some reason the `query` arg is required or this will not work.  But it can be an empty string.

---

You might be interested in an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), which adds a few more powerful features to find and search including the ability to resolve path variables like `${relativeFile}`, `${relativeFileDirname}`, etc. in the "files to include/exclude" fields.